# 404 Page Not Found (The page you requested was not found.)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, localhost

I try to show (*localhost/ujian/index.php/user_controller*)
but not found, why?

**Code**

```
class User_controller extends CI_Controller{

function __construct()
{
    parent ::__construct();
      $this->load->model('user_model');
      $this->load->helper(array('form'));
}

function user()
{
    $data['judul'] = 'Daftar User';
    $this->load->view('user', $data);
}

function simpan_user()
{   

    $this->user_model->simpan_user();
    $data['notifikasi'] = 'Data berhasil disimpan';
    $data['judul']='Insert Data Berhasil';
    $this->load->view('notifikasi', $data);
    redirect('user_controller');
}
 function view()
{
    $data['daftar_user'] = $this->user_model->get_user_all();
    $this->load->view('daftar_user', $data);
}
 function delete_user($id)
{
    $data['daftar_user'] = $this->user_model->get_user_all();
    $this->load->view('daftar_user', $data);
    $username = $this->user_model->delete_user($id);
    redirect('user_controller');
}
```

I try to show (*localhost/ujian/index.php/user_controller*)
but not found, why?

Comment: add your controller class name code lines..

Comment: what is the url your are calling?

Comment: this url : http://localhost/ujian/index.php/user_controller

Comment: class already in the add .(class User_controller extends CI_Controller)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you are calling the URL:

```
localhost/ujian/index.php/user_controller
```

But your controler doesn't have default function index(). So add default function and do default action for this url.

```
function index()
{
    // add your action
    // or call any default function like $this->user();
}
```

Comment: OMG, u are very smart about codeigniter..thanks..Can you help me make a web?I am still learning how to make a web with CodeIgniter

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354393/a-php-error-was-encountered-codeigniter-line-number-19

Answer (score 0):

When You don't Specify any function name after controller name, It call the index() function by default.

In your Requested URL there is no function name specified, So, It by default call the index() function . But There is no Index() function defined in your requested controller .

Please , Create an index() function and try.

Cheers..!!